# Get max or min n-elements out of numpy array? (preferably not flattened)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, slice

I know that I can get min or max values with:

```
max(matrix)
min(matrix)
```

out of a numpy matrix/vector. The indices for those vales are returned by:

```
argmax(matrix)
argmin(matrix)
```

So e.g. when I have a 5x5 matrix:

```
a = np.arange(5*5).reshape(5, 5) + 10

# array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
#        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
#        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])
```

I could get the max value via:

```
In [86]: np.max(a) # getting the max-value out of a
Out[86]: 34

In [87]: np.argmax(a) # index of max-value 34 is 24 if array a were flattened
Out[87]: 24
```

...but what is the most efficient way to get the max or min n-elements?

So let's say out of *a* I want to have the 5 highest and 5 lowest elements. This should return me `[30, 31, 32, 33, 34]` for the 5 highest values respectively `[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]` for their indices. Likewise `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]` for the 5 lowest values and `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` for the indices of the 5 lowest elements.

What would be an efficient, reasonable solution for this?

**My first idea** was **flattening and sorting** the array and taking the last and first 5 values. Afterwards I search through the original 2D matrix for the indices of those values. **Although this procedure works flattening + sorting isn't very efficient...does anyone know a faster solution?**

Additionally I would like to have the indices of the original 2D array and not the flattening one. So instead of `24` returned by `np.argmax(a)` I would like to have `(4, 4)`.

Comment: `np.partition` (and `np.argpartition` for the indices) is O(n) - I think this is the best you can hope for here. It requires ravelling the array first (this should just create a view and so not incur any performance penalty). You could then use `unravel_index` to get the 2D indices in your original array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to get the indices of the largest or smallest values in an array is to use [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). This function uses an introselect algorithm and runs with linear complexity - this performs better than fully sorting for larger arrays (which is typically O(n log n)).

By default this function works along the last axis of the array. To consider an entire array, you need to use [`ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). For example, here's a random array `a`:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 5))
>>> a
array([[60, 68, 86, 66,  9],
       [66, 26, 83, 87, 50],
       [41, 26,  0, 55,  9],
       [57, 80, 71, 50, 22],
       [94, 30, 95, 99, 76]])
```

Then to get the indices of the five largest values in the (flattened) 2D array, use:

```
>>> i = np.argpartition(a.ravel(), -5)[-5:] # argpartition(a.ravel(), 5)[:5] for smallest
>>> i
array([ 2,  8, 22, 23, 20])
```

To get back the corresponding 2D indices of these positions in `a`, use [`unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
>>> i2d = np.unravel_index(i, a.shape)
>>> i2d
(array([0, 1, 4, 4, 4]), array([2, 3, 2, 3, 0]))
```

Then indexing `a` with `i2d` gives back the five largest values:

```
>>> a[i2d]
array([86, 87, 95, 99, 94])
```

Comment: in this case, sorting is faster : `%timeit a.ravel.argpartition(-5) -> 5.5 µs` and `%timeit a.ravel.argsort() -> 3.8 µs`. But of course with bigger arrays, this is the right way.